# Visual Studio 2015 Community C# Calculator Code Errors

Tags: c#

I wrote a test example code which I am having issues with. The code'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SEC3_LEC19 {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

      int x, y;
      string num1, num2, choice = "yes";
      char op;
      bool again = true;

      while (again) {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter two integers");
        // First Number
        Console.Write("Enter num1: ");
        num1 = Console.ReadLine();

        // Second Number
        Console.Write("Enter num2: ");
        num2 = Console.ReadLine();

        // The Operator
        Console.Write(
          "Enter the operation [+ - * /]: ");
        op = (char)Console.Read();

        if (int.TryParse(num1, out x)) {
          ;
        } else {
          Console.WriteLine(
            num1 + " is NaN val set to 0");
        }

        if (int.TryParse(num2, out y)) {
          ;
        } else {
          Console.WriteLine(
            num2 + " is NaN val set to 0");
        }

        switch (op) {
          case '+':
            Console.WriteLine(
              x + " + " + y + " = " + (x + y));
            break;
          case '-':
            Console.WriteLine(
              x + " - " + y + " = " + (x - y));
            break;
          case '*':
            Console.WriteLine(
              x + " * " + y + " = " + (x * y));
            break;
          case '/':
            if (y == 0) {
              Console.WriteLine(
                "Division by zero not allowed!");
            } else {
              Console.WriteLine(
                x + " / " + y + " = " + (x - y));
            }
            break;
          default:
            Console.WriteLine(
              "Operator Unrecognized");
            break;
        }

        // Offer user to try again
        Console.Write("Go again? [yes/no]: ");

        // Read user input [NOT WORKING]
        choice = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (choice.ToLower()) {
          case "yes":
            again = true;
            break;
          case "no":
            again = false;
            break;
          default:
            Console.WriteLine(
              "Unrecognized choice!");
            break;
        }
      }

      // **********************************************
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

The code uses a while loop, via the console, to ask the user to enter two numbers, then an operator after which it performs and displays the calculation results.  It them moves on to ask the user if they would like to try again.  It uses a `choice = Console.ReadLine()` statement.  Based on the answer the code is to either continue with a while loop, or break out of the loop.  Unfortunately, the compiler appears to skip that choice part and just goes ahead into the switch statement.  There are similar statements at the top of the code and those work fine.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't link to your code.  Include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Quantic He means it is supposed to wait for user input.

Comment: Can you show the omitted part? How do you read the values for the two numbers?

Comment: Actually that code "has to work". Can you put a Thread.Sleep(1500); before the .Write("go again?") so you make sure you dont press enter to long(maybe another readline before that readline)?

Comment: I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because, you use Console.Read() on line 34. It reads one character and when you hit ENTER it also reads the return key. So in the buffer there's already a key and it skips ReadLine() and reads it as a line feed.

Comment: Hmm, I did not think about that.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you change `op` to be a string, and you `ReadLine()` instead of `Read()`, then that will make sure there are no pending/hidden characters in your input stream. Then, your switch checks if `op` is the string `"+"`, `"-"`, `"*"` .. etc and not the char `'+'`, `'-'` .. etc.

I also fixed your indentation. Please follow this style in all your future implementations so it is better to read and understand:

This should work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SEC3_LEC19
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int x, y;
            string num1, num2, choice = "yes";
            string op; // changed to string
            bool again = true;

            while (again)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter two integers");

                Console.Write("Enter num1: ");
                num1 = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Enter num2: ");
                num2 = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Enter the operation [+ - * /]: ");
                op = Console.ReadLine(); // Read line instead of Read char

                if (!int.TryParse(num1, out x))
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 + " is NaN val set to 0");

                if (!int.TryParse(num2, out y))
                    Console.WriteLine(num2 + " is NaN val set to 0");

                switch (op)
                {
                    // Changed cases
                    case "+": Console.WriteLine( x + " + " + y + " = " + (x + y)); break;
                    case "-": Console.WriteLine( x + " - " + y + " = " + (x - y)); break;
                    case "*": Console.WriteLine( x + " * " + y + " = " + (x * y)); break;
                    case "/":
                        if (y == 0)
                            Console.WriteLine("Division by zero not allowed!");
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine( x + " / " + y + " = " + (x - y));
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Operator Unrecognized"); break;
                }

                Console.Write("Go again? [yes/no]: ");

                choice = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (choice.ToLower())
                {
                    case "yes": again = true; break;
                    case "no": again = false; break;
                    default: Console.WriteLine( "Unrecognized choice!"); break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awsome! 

On a side note, I am using a rather small monitor, hence my code formatting has to spread out more vertically than horizontally.  But I will try to format the code for stackoverflow in the pastebin.

I appreciate everyone's assistance :)

Comment: Mark, glad we were able to help. Practice a good coding style and good luck. Mark / upvote answers that were helpful :)